# Properties of functions that are both quasiconcave and quasiconvex

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

If a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is both quasiconcave and quasiconvex, what does this imply about $f$? For example, I know that a monotone function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^1$ is both quasiconcave and quasiconvex. Is the converse true? And what about for $n>1$?